# How to pass UTF-8 into ContentType c#?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

I have `Vietnam` char in console app it is working fine.

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Console.WriteLine("BỐN TRĂM");
```

But when I tried to do it in api call it is giving wrong char.

```
correct = BỐN TRĂM
wrong = Bễ́N TRĂM
```

api call code -

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

                var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(apiUserName + ":" + apiPassword);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, APIURL);
                request.Content = new StringContent(xmlRequestBody, Encoding.Unicode, "text/xml");
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("charset", "utf-8"));
```

why it is working wrong in api?

Comment: `StringContent(xmlRequestBody, Encoding.UTF8,...` ? Though i am completely sure i have misunderstood your question

Comment: Looks like you put UTF-16 in the charset header (last line).  Also it looks like you have 2 different httpClient's... one called "httpClient" and the other "ProcessInvoiceDetail.httpClient", but you are not showing any code that uses either one of them.

Comment: let me update question

Comment: The Net Library doesn't like first line of Xml that contains UTF-16.  Usually what works is to use ReadLine() to skip the ident line of the xml and then you can parse with standard xml classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass like this and try:

```
 request.Content = new StringContent(xmlRequestBody, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
```

Comment: I tried this too same wrong char i'm getting any other formatting we can try? pls guide thanks

Comment: not getting any error but some char are wrong :( how to add like this?
 request.Content.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("charset", "utf-8"));